# Chromes Dev tools do not show all source files. Is this normal or a bug?

Tags: angular, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, webpack-dev-server

I have a Angular-cli project that is served through webpack's dev-server.

In my project I'm successfully able to make GET request to a json mock file I have setup for the project.

angular.json config:

```
        // app-models folder being added includes .mock.json files
        "assets": [
            {
              "glob": "**/*",
              "input": "src/app/_app-models",
              "output": "/models/app-models"
            },
        ]
```

In my network tab, I'm able to successfully request my mock json data.

[image]

Although I'm unable to find this json data anywhere in my sources tab. (/models folder is not listed in localhost:4200)
[image]

Is this a bug in chrome dev tools or is it really meant to not be there? **How do I find this json file?**

Comment: The dev tools doesn't show files that are not being rendered in that specified moment. Are you sure that that file is being rendered or used in this moment?

Comment: @JacopoSciampi The file starts out as a .json file and is moved over with Angular-cli's config (angular.json -> "assets" option). The json file is then requested (HttpClient.get()) after the app is bootstraped (around app.components ngOnInit() lifecycle hook)

Comment: @Jonathan002 did you find the answer to your question?

Comment: happened here. could not find css files under source tab.